# ASIHTTPRequest crashes on iOS 3.1.3

Tags: ios, crash, asihttprequest, ios-3.x

My application crashes as soon as I call [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]; on my iPod Touch 1G. It has no issue on iOS 4.x.

The error I see is Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=10 UserInfo=0x368790 "NSRangeException"

and the backtrace I get from a crash manager system I have implemented is

```
backtrace: (
"0   MayasDUp                            0x0007f21b -[SWCrashManager backtrace] + 18",
"1   MayasDUp                            0x0007ece1 sighandler + 144",
"2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x3049e7eb _sigtramp + 26",
"3   MayasDUp                            0x0005128b -[ASIHTTPRequest buildPostBody] + 850"
```

)

I even placed the [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] call alone, without performing anything else like setting post variables and starting the connection. The crash still happens.

I've placed breakpoints and log NSLogs inside ASIHTTPRequest but nothing useful came out.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Can you run it through in the debugger and show us exactly which line in buildPostBody it's crashing at?

Comment: The buildPostBody method is fully executed. I placed a NSLog call and a breakpoint at the very end of the method and the execution reaches that point normally.

The app crashes on Thread 3 and it only displays a 0 <????> node for additional details.

It seems that the crash happens after a small delay and it cannot be displayed properly.

Comment: Have you run through with NSZombies enabled?

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get NSZombie to show up... But 
after digging a bit deeper showed that the issue comes from an [NSArray objectAtIndex:] call, where it tries to access [6] but the length is 4. That explains the NSRangeException error I get. I placed NSLogs before every objectAtIndex call inside the ASIHTTPRequest class, but there was no array accessing such an index.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on objectAtIndex instead?

Comment: First of all, I realised  that the crash happens only when the device has Internet access.

Then I moved on from the [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] single line crash, which was not my main issue anyway.

I managed to get a console output: [STATUS] Starting asynchronous request <ASIFormDataRequest: 0x82f600>
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (--??--) failed to 
return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: 
kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this message again, so I don't recall 
what was at the (--??--) place-holder above.

Comment: I found the full message, it's:
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (<CFNotificationCenter 0x5e199c0 [0x1a6a3e0]>) failed to 
return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: 
kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, I found that the issue was very deep and it actually was a compiler bug.

In short, using LLVM 2.0 and setting Optimization Level > None for the project resulted in corrupted compiled files (ASIHTTPRequest and ASIFormDataRequest) which caused the crash and provided no real data in the stack trace.

The solution we applied was to leave Compiler and Optimization settings intact and add a -O0 compiler flag for the 2 ASIHttp files that had the issue.

Other users reported that XCode 4.0.2 fixed the compiler issue.

For anyone interested, there are some details here:
http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/c598649bfe71643c/8ee09defd12386ba?lnk=gst&q=crashes#8ee09defd12386ba

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something running on the main thread that is taking over 10 seconds. Are you doing synchronous http requests? You must use:

```
[request startAsynchronous];
```

if you're on the main thread.

Comment: I am using startAsynchronous.

Comment: There's something else that is taking a long time to run then. Either trying running through with instruments to see where the time is going, or pausing in the debugger before the timeout happens, or using logging, or post more code.